# MVC 3 routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Well, technically it is an ASP.net routing question but since I am using MVC 3 here we go.

I need to setup a route as follows:
http://www.mysite.com/profile/1 where 1 is the userid, however I want to hide the userid param in the query string because it is just plain ugly.

Controller is ProfileController
Action is Index
parameter is userid.

I can't seem to figure this out. I am probably thinking about it too much...
Any help would be ultra cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route should be nice and simple.  It needs to come before your default route handler.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Profile",                                              // Route name
        "profile/{userId}",                                    // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index" }        // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Comment: doesn't it need to look like route.Maproute blah blah?

Comment: Yeah :) I was being lazy and trying to do it from memory.  Answer updated.

Comment: So something like this:  routes.MapRoute("Profile",
                            "/profile/{userid}", new {controller = "profile", action = "index"});

Comment: ok, I put that in but now I get The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
Parameter name: routeUrl

Comment: @CodeJammr That's because you need to omit the `/` in your "/profile/{userid}" string.  It should just be "profile/{userid}"

Comment: http://www.dfwforsale.com/Profile/12 I have the route debugger up. Looks like the action is getting skipped

Comment: I removed the slashes,, saw that :)

Comment: Anything after profile in the route gets interpreted as the action... interesting

Comment: @CodeJammr Sorry, I know my original code messed you up a bit, but I was pretty quick to correct it.  I should have mentioned that this code MUST go above the default route.